# Spring MVC POST method

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, http-post

Here is my Controller class snippet

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createAgent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createAgent(@RequestBody String json) {
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

How do I go about passing a JSON object to this method. Can I pass it through the url in any way? If I pass this way(although this seems very wrong),

```
http://localhost:8080/SurveyApp3/createAgent/{"a_id": 8746574632, "pwd": "abcd", "pim_id": 3, "m_id":9738247882}
```

I get an error saying

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SurveyApp3/createAgent/%7B%22a_id%22:%208746574632,%20%22pwd%22:%20%22abcd%22,%20%22pim_id%22:%203,%20%22m_id%22:9738247882%7D] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

I also tried using an ajax request from the welcome file index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" >

 function sendAjax() {

 $.ajax({
     url: "/createAgent",
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: "{\"a_id\":7645534265,\"pwd\":\"abcd\", \"pim_id\":3, \"m_id\":9738247882}",
     contentType: 'application/json',
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data.a_id + " " + data.pwd);
    },
    error:function(data,status,er) {
       alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }
 });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i go to this url,

```
http://localhost:8080/SurveyApp3/createAgent
```

I get an error saying GET method not supported. I am still new to this topic and I am not able to figure out how to send a JSON object as parameter to a post method.
Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: When you visit a URL in a browser (like http://localhost:8080/SurveyApp3/createAgent) the default method is GET. As your method is POST, the server returns 405 Not Supported.

Comment: How do I pass a JSON value to the method then? I don't exactly know what and how (@RequestBody String json) gets its value.

Comment: What happens when you run the AJAX call?

Comment: I get this error WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: Have you tried $.post instead? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: use @pathVariable instead.

Comment: @Shailesh: says WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Controller every method must return a view name. In your code that is missing that's why you are getting 
**WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI**  error, add 
 **return "viewname"**  to your code. 
Also, use @ModelAttribute --- for Objects 
          @PathVariable   --- for Strings 
          @RequestParam   --- for String arrays.

Hope this will work...

Comment: Isn't that only to render some response on the web page? Anyway I tried returning the String (return json;) but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller keep this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createAgent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createAgent(@RequestParam String jsonText) {
    System.out.println(jsonText);
}
```

In your Ajax call keep this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/createAgent",
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
     "jsonText":"{'a_id':7645534265,'pwd':'abcd', 'pim_id':3,'m_id':9738247882}"
            },
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data.a_id + " " + data.pwd);
    },
    error:function(data,status,er) {
       alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }
 });
```

Hope it will be helpful. :)

Comment: Says WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported. Do I need to add Get method also in RequestMethod?

Answer (score 0):

- First try to check next dependencies:

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>
  ```
- Have you send your post URL using a button, yes? Have you configure it to invoke "sendAjax()" method?
- You can check the url typed in Ajax (check the right syntax of line :

url: "/createAgent"

Maybe you've  made a typing mistake using "/" symbol

- And in the end there is a Json Converter. Have you defined it in your bean configuration?

Comment: I am not using maven. But I did add jackson jar.